# error when pulling data from database to 2 dimensional array in jsp

Tags: database, jsp, multidimensional-array

```
var myData = new Array();
var i =0;

myData[i] = [];

<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
myData[0][i]= <c:out value="${row.time_in_hr}"/>
myData[1][i]= <c:out value="${row.tph}"/>

document.write(myData[0][i]);

i++;


</c:forEach>
```

Hi all,
I'm trying to copy data from sql table into a 2 dimensional array. but I'm getting this error:

Error: TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

the error is at this line myData[1][i]=  in the code
if i do this with a single dimensional array it works. and the myData[i][0] is working fine.. so any idea?? thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you please post the original code in an edit? The above looks like a mixture of JSTL (i.e. '<c:...') and java scriptlets that are in your JSP file. Also, if you could provide the data that is causing the problem that could help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this question .. instead of

```
myData[0][i]= <c:out value="${row.time_in_hr}"/>
myData[1][i]= <c:out value="${row.tph}"/>
```

do the below changes:

```
    myData[i] = [ <c:out value="${row.time_in_hr}"/>,
            <c:out value="${row.tph}"/> ];
```

because you can't declare two dimensional array, so instead for each element if you want to insert more than one value. just put comma between the values.